# Remove columns on a matrix based on column names using R

Tags: r, matrix, filtering

There should be a super simple solution but I'm getting conflicting information so asking here. Basically I have a simple 5x5 matrix. I would like to filter out select columns using their names.
Here is an example of the data:
[Example Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi3lm.png)

I would like to do something like `filter(column c)` and the resulting matrix would be a 5x4 matrix without column c. To my knowledge dplyr filter doesn't work with matrices. Apologies if there's an easy solution to this.

Comment: Is it a matrix or data.frame?  If it is dataframe `subset(data, select = -c)` if it is matrix use `data[, setdiff(colnames(data), "c")]` `filter` is used filtering the rows and not columns

Comment: It's a matrix. I just tried it and it worked. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `setdiff` on the column names to get all names that are not the 'c'

```
data[, setdiff(colnames(data), "c")]
```